# iphone store photos in application after clicking photo using camera

Tags: iphone, image, camera, exif

I want to click photos using the camera through the application. then store the photo in the application. Is it possible? Can anyone Please tell me how this can be achieved. I also want to know if the .EXIF data will be retained along with the image.Please help.

Answer (score 3):

This concept takes screenshot  from the app & later using them

1.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), &context);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
    NSString *imageName = @"temp.png";

    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

Above code takes screenshot of the view & save this image in the documentsDirectory as "temp.png"
```

2.

```
    NSInteger primaryKeyValue = 1;
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.png"];
    NSString *filePath2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.png",primaryKeyValue ]];
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileMgr moveItemAtPath:fullPathToFile toPath:filePath2 error:nil];
```

3.
    Later, if you want to use this image

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *uniquePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.png",primaryKeyValue ]]; 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:uniquePath];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me what exactly is screenshot? I dint understand it properly. And Whre shoul I implement this code? shoul I put them in    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

Comment: Basically what happens is I have a button on a view , on clicking that button I saving an image of whatever is visible on screen.Screenshot is basically an image of whatever you are seeing on screen.Please accept the answer, if it helped you

Comment: Ye it had helped me in a way. But I wan to take a photo using the camera and then store the photo. The saving part and the later part  is helpfull.Please help me